# Bootstrap dropdown и перенос текста

Tags: html, bootstrap

Не могу догадаться как сделать перенос текста в `dropdown bootstrap`.

```
<div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Еще
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Многогогогогогогоогогого текста</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">чуть-чуть</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Суть в том, что при смене разрешения экрана текст просто вылазит за границы.
Уже перепробовала везде ставить ограничения на максимальную ширину, толку ноль(

https://codepen.io/apollinem1/pen/GRrPdZN

Там сразу будет понятен мой вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бутстрапе 4 у ссылок с классом `dropdown-item` по умолчанию задан стиль `white-space: nowrap`. Переопределите его на `white-space: normal`.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое)